# В каком из предложений имеется обособленное обстоятельство с уступительным значением?

Tags: предложение

В каком из предложений имеется обособленное обстоятельство с уступительным значением?

> 1. Несмотря на то что было поздно, гости не расходились.
> 2. Несмотря на округлость форм холмом, нам легко можно было выбрать
>    ровную площадку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое предложение сложноподчиненное с придаточным уступительным, которое присоединяется подчинительным союзом "несмотря на то что". (Поздно - не обстоятельство, было поздно - грамматическая основа). Второе предложение простое, осложнено обособленным обстоятельством с предлогом "несмотря на" (с уступительным значением).

Answer (score 1):

Обстоятельство есть **только** во втором предложении ("несмотря на округлость форм холмов").

Первое предложение -- сложноподчинённое. Никаких обстоятельств в нём не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение первое.  Обособленное обстоятельство - поздно.